# Problems playing MP4 videos on Android from Apache server

Tags: android, apache, video

I'm having an issue when trying to play an MP4 video (using the HTML5  tag) using an Android web browser.

I've tried both just using the straight HTML5 and the Video.JS plugin (videojs.com) and am having the same issues in both cases.  To describe what I'm seeing:

Videos on my site won't play when browsing from Android.  I tap to play and get an error dialog box that reads "Cannot play video.  Sorry, this video cannot be played."

When using Video.JS, I originally thought this might be a video encoding problem, so in an effort to try to isolate things, I grabbed the code and the video from the home page of videojs.com (which works fine on Android) and put them up on my test server (running apache).  Things worked fine on iPhone but not on android.

As a second step, I put the same code and file grabbed from videojs.com and put them on a different dev server running IIS.  From there, any Android I test with works great.

This implies to me that it's a server configuration problem, but this is where I'm stumped.  I've got both apache and IIS configured correctly for the mime types for mp4 files (video/mp4).  I've verified this by looking at the HTTP headers when requesting the file from both servers.

Does anyone have any ideas of what other settings to look at?  Clearly the code is correct, and it works great from an IIS server, but for some reason when served from my Apache server it fails to play correctly on Android.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Evan

Comment: Are you sure the video is capable of being played on a mobile device? There are a lot of videos that aren't mobile-friendly, and will end up throwing a "This Video Cannot Be Played" error. The MediaPlayer on Android can only play "progressive streamable contents" which basically means: 1. the movie atom has to precede all the media data atoms. 2. The clip has to be reasonably interleaved. If it doesn't, you'll get the error I mentioned above.

Comment: Given that the same video works on an IIS server properly, it doesn't seem like it's a problem with the video itself.  It's only when the video's placed on an Apache server that it doesn't play.

Comment: Is there a difference in how user-agent strings are handled between your apache and IIS server?  i.e. content being transformed based on UA?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, then I found out that Android doesn't like secure HTTP addresses. Once I removed the "s" from the HTTP link, presto it finally works. So your link should look something like this:

```
<video width='640' height='360' src='http://domain.net/video/640x360_example.mp4' type='video/mp4' id='player1' autoplay='autoplay' controls='controls' preload='none'></video>
```

Hopefully this helps you! I spent 10 months looking for this soltuion. :)